# Removing carriage returns in report studio

Tags: cognos

I need to be able to remove carriage returns from a free text field in Report Studio so when its exported to CSV, its all on one line. I DO NOT have access to native SQL, this is locked out, I can only do this through report studio. I have tried replace combined with Char(13) + Char(10) and it just errors. Has anyone managed to do this with a data item, or text item?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace() is not a built-in Cognos function. It's a vendor-specific function. For instance, Oracle, DB2, MySql and MS SQL all have a replace() function though their syntax might differ. What is your data source type?

Comment: Hi Jonsonium, That was exactly the problem, I had to use TRANSLATE instead of REPLACE, and CHAR(13) was CHR(13). Thanks for your response!